# Google Cloud Instance Crashed - Same Attached Disk Crashes another instance when attached as secondary (unmounted)

Tags: ssh, hard-drive, boot, cloud

I have a GCP instance that is micro, and I suspect it ran out of memory,
It crashed and does not let me SSH into it, even through the web console on GCP.

I create a new bootable instance and enter it OK,  but when I attach the "broken" disk to this instance as a secondary attached Disk after the working bootable, the new instance does not boot, and gives the same error as the other that broke.

Any ideas how I can restore / recover the broken disk?